# visual basic 6, trying to rebuild non-working project

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

We have been given the  'latest' project files, and they don't compile.  So we are trying to reconstruct the solution and restore it to a working state.  We copied all the modules and forms into one project and yet when we compile it is not picking up all the form events, such as Form_Activate.  The events are there, spelled correctly, but are not being picked up.  If you do a '.' with intellisense the events are not listed either...

Why is this? Is there a way to get visual basic 6 to reload the form in order to pick up the events, etc?

Comment: There's no such thing as Visual Studio 2006- do you mean 2005 or 2008? This is for Winforms?

Comment: Would your VB source code be Visual Basic 6 code?

Comment: pcampbell is correct!  I hope everybody else can forgive my error! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Check to be sure you have both the event handler ...

```
private void Form1_Activated( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
  // Your code here
}
```

... and the wire-up usually found in the FormName.Designer.cs file ...

```
this.Activated += new System.EventHandler( this.Form1_Activated );
```

If you have moved the event handlers over, but not the event registrations, your event handlers will not get called.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that the designer files were omitted from the code completely, and since they don't have a good project the file they didn't re-generate correctly.  It's possibly even a visual studio version mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no Visual Studio 2006.
Second what are the errors you get when you try to compiler?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably having a scope problem. Does the events have any accessibility modifiers such as `Public` or `Private`?